# Java auto-update jar files- Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jar, auto-update

I have designed a Desktop based GUI on Eclipse using Windows Builder and I have added few external jar files.
Now, I am looking to implement a mechanism which checks the updated version of those external jar files and download automatically. Replacement of these .jar files will be done manually.

Can anyone give me an advice which technique will be suitable ?

Your advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You probably don't want to change the JAR files on a user's computer until you've updated the JAR files in your development environment and tested to make sure your Swing application still works.  After that, you can push the JAR files to users any way you want.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc ,Exactly, I want to update the jar files only on my development environment. Can you suggest the techniques which I can look for ?

Comment: Usually, I don't update my development environment unless I'm forced to do so by obsolescence or bugs.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc,Many thanks for your prompt reply. I would like to know is there any automatic method for updating JAR files ? Since I faced a issue due to outdated library and then I looked manually for it, So, is there any solution that I can write some code that automatically checks for the external jars ?